# Excel Force Calculate formulas after C# .ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, ms-office

How can I force calculation of formulas after using code to change excel sheet.
The same as clicking CTRL + ALT + F9 in Excel?

This is the code that execute the command successfully on Excel document:

```
                OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                myCommand.Connection = Conn;
                myCommand.CommandText = updateSQL;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please add some further details

Comment: If you have a reference to the Excel Application you can call the `CalculateFull` or `CalculateFullRebuild` methods.  Your question is difficult to answer without at least mentioning how you're interfacing with the Excel file.